# Python String Permutations Up To 2 Letter Changes Per Permutation

Tags: python

How would I make a permutation generator in python but limit the changes to only 2 letters?

Example:

```
create_perm('cow')
```

returns

```
['cwo', 'woc', 'ocw']
```

but not `'wco'` since that would mean three letters have changed their position.

Comment: pull-rigth - do you mean indentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only two letters are allowed to change, this boils down to swapping two letters:

```
from itertools import combinations

def changetwo(s):
    for i,j in combinations(range(len(s)), 2):
        res = list(s)
        res[i], res[j] = res[j], res[i]
        yield ''.join(res)
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(changetwo('cow'))
['ocw', 'woc', 'cwo']
>>> for x in changetwo('1234'):
...     x
... 
'2134'
'3214'
'4231'
'1324'
'1432'
'1243'
```